# Catalano framework for image processing

Tags: java, image, image-processing

I am developing one `java` application for image processing i.e image binarization,image thinning etc. Somewhere I come to know about the [Catalano Framework](https://code.google.com/p/catalano-framework/).I have downloaded the .zip file for that framework.But i did not find any documentation in that jar so that it will tell us

How to use that framework? or 
Any example using that framework? or
How to binarize the image using this framework?

So could anyone help me in finding example for Image processing using `Catalano Framework`.

Comment: Have you tried the [downloads section](https://code.google.com/p/catalano-framework/downloads/list) from the project home page?

Comment: Yes i have downloaded the remaining files also and now i have the sample examples.

Answer (score 3):

Contains the documentation in the folder:
Documentation\javadoc\index.html

and the samples in the folder:
Samples\Desktop\Imaging.

Example with binarization:

```
FastBitmap fb = new FastBitmap("c:\\files\\image.jpg");
fb.toGrayscale();

Threshold t = new Threshold(120);
t.applyInPlace(fb);

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, fb.toIcon());
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can found it on [Aforge](http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/features/) framework documentation since this library has the same architecture as the Aforge.